# Esoteric language with 5 operators

Tags: esoteric-languages

I need to implement a Brainfuck language like(?) language

There are 5 commands for the language.

Initially,

> int x=1; at start of the execution of the algorithm

Each command does the following in C language.

**"+"**: x+=1;

**"-"**: x-=1;

**">"**: x= x*2;

**"<"** : x= x/2;

**"!"** : printf("%c",x);

**Input** is a sequence of characters that have ASCII codes between 0 to 127.

**output** should be a sequence of the commands above so that the program prints the same sequence of characters as the input

Note that the length of the output should be minimized.

> For example
>
> input: ABC
>
> Output: >>>>>>+!+!+!
>
> ***explanation***: ASCII code for A B C are 65 66 67 receptively
>
> x=1 so x is doubled 6 times to get to 64. Then increment and print 3 times to print all ABC.
>
> This is minimal compared to increasing x 64 times to get to x=65

I need to implement this language.

But I am stuck on thinking up an algorithm that finds the sequence of commands when moving onto the next character in the input.

For instance, when x=8 and needs to move to 12, decrease x twice then multiplying by 2 is faster than adding 4 times. The decision for the algorithm gets very complicated when numbers get large enough.

I am thinking about recursion maybe to find the path? for minimum number of commands.

Any hints or is there a name of this esoteric language that I can refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of finding the minimum number of steps to go from one value of `x` to another is using a modified [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm).

It comes down to maintaining a list of to numbers to explore, which will be initialized to your starting number. When you explore a number, you take all possible steps, i.e. `+`, `-`, `>` and `<`, keeping track of the result (and how you got there), until you reach your destination.

This will find a path from your start number to the destination number, and it will be guaranteed to be the shortest.

Comment: Sorry I should have made the question clearer.
The value x does not reset to 1 each time the next letter is found.
So from the example "ABC" the ASCII for "A" which is 65. After printing A, B is found by adding 1 to x which is 66.
Dijkstra only finds shortest path from a certain value to all other vertices. So the shortest path from say x=1 to all others is found. But this is not enough since the I need to know the list of commands from "current x" to the next character's ASCII value.

Comment: So for example for printing "ABC", x starts from 1 reaches 65, 66, 67. So I am either considering using Floyd Warshall by
1. making a matrix 128x128 size to find a shortest path from each position to another.
2. maybe use single source and single destination shortest path algorithm to find a shortest path from current x to next. But I think it will be wasteful as it might use redundant values?

Comment: Any of the algorithms you propose should do the trick. If you are worried about being wasteful, consider [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)